# Standalone server bundled with blazor server application

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, kestrel

I need to create an application that will operate on a windows 10 machine and needs to be reached from mobile clients and other desktop clients.
I figured i'd need an application that has a web interface and possibli be a pwa.
This could allow me to use it on mobile without coding an app for android and one for ios.
My question is, is it possible to ship the application with a standalone webserver so that the customer has to install nothig but my app?
I looked into Kestrel but i have no idea on how to setup the project as it visual studio 2022 (preview) keeps using IIS.
What could be my options?

Comment: You can run IIS on windows 10. I assume you are aware the mobile devices will need to be connected to the internal network unless you plan on exposing that machine to the Internet (which is a bad idea)?

Comment: It is an application that's supposed to work only among the lan of a workplace. So yes, all the mobile devices are on the internal Network. I managed to make it work with Kestrel. What worries me now is, am i going to be able to use kestrel in production for it is a low amount of connections scenario (about 5 or 6).

Comment: Yes, you can use Kestrel. Even when you host in IIS, Kestrel is used and IIS is only a reverse proxy for it. If you are concerned about its performance then you need not worry, it is incredibly performant.

Comment: I'm more worried about wether it is shippable with the application or not. As in, if i public to a local folder, and then move the files on the machine they're supposed to work on, will kestrel be already there or doi have to install it separately on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and consider this thread closed for I discovered i don't need to transition to C# and dotNet to create what I need as SpringBoot offers me just that.

Comment: Please mark the question as closed using the 'Close' option under your question (you can find it with other options like Share, Edit, Delete, Flag)

Comment: I would do it if the option was there. i only have Share, edit, flag, delete